# Where are the sun hats?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

All of the hats seem to be winter hats, however, it's not winter down here it's summer. There should be sun hats and maybe some sunscreen.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there *is* a sun hat: [Where in the World](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/where-in-the-world-sun)...

Your problem is known to the company; see for example this footnote to the [Winter Bash 2015 blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/12/14/announcing-winter-bash-2015/):

> 1: As in the past, tradition defeated accuracy in the naming decision. Hopefully some of our summertime audience will be at least partially mollified by the fact that the Winter Bash site will be available in Portuguese, Spanish, Japanese and Russian this year, thanks to the efforts of our international Community Managers.

Unfortunately, [you're in the minority](https://sciencing.com/differences-between-northern-southern-hemisphere-8260091.html), and it's IMHO not likely to be changed. At least you have good weather to pair with the Bash...

Comment: Where are sun-lamp hats for those who of us who are north in the northern hemisphere? ;D